# Anchor Tag href redirects to an untitled page

Tags: html, django

I want to use an `<a/>` tag which redirects to some page. But the problem is that when I click it, it doesn't open, and when I click on open in a new tab, it doesn't load properly. The url is correct but it won't load.

You can see that the url is properly loaded, but the page wont load.

[image]

But when I simply press enter in url, it loads somehow.

[image]

Here's how I gave the href.

```
<a href="{{HOST_BASE_URL}}art/search/category/paintings/">
```

It works if I manually add the value of `{{HOSE_BASE_URL}}` like this:

```
 <a href="http://localhost:8000/art/search/category/paintings/">
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: **Remember** one that is ```<a>``` tag does not redirect to url you specified but append your current url in address bar with what it has in its ```href````.

Answer (score 0):

What do you see in console and server logs when visiting the URL from  tag?  The URL in the above code and the screenshots is different, please add more details if the issue is happening for every URL or only a select one.

Comment: oh sorry i uploaded different code, i updated the a tags now, To answer your question, i dont see any error in console. And when i simply press enter in the url of the first picture, the page loads. Do you know why this is happening